# How to diagnose Android ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, concurrency, runtime-error

I have an Android Google Maps app that I'm debugging through Eclipse. I'm getting this error:

```
    12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:41)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-14 16:19:50.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I never explicitly use an iterator (my code has none, although obviously some call includes one), and I've made sure that any sort of list is only accessed through what is returned from `Collections.synchronizedList`, which should have solved this, to my limited understanding. As I have no idea what in my code base would cause this, I can't really post code snippets. Does anyone know  other "normal" causes? Or how to get any meaningful location from the logcat printout (to what I can tell, the only files references are library files)?

Comment: "I never explicitly use an iterator" -- You will notice that it is `onDraw()` of `MapView` that has the iterator. "as I can't seem to copy and paste from LogCat" -- in Eclipse, highlight the lines in LogCat and press Ctrl-C.

Comment: Collections.synchronizedList does nothing to solve this actually.  If the list is changed while an iterator is in use (which includes the enhanced for-loop) that exception will happen.  synchronizing individual method calls does not stop altering the list in between iterator calls.

Comment: I saw that it was onDraw of MapView, however that's not code I wrote, so I'm assuming it's autogenerated or library code? What might I be doing that would cause a problem for code I didn't write?

Comment: (sorry this is so nebulous, but I assume it would be bad form for me to copy-paste a massive code chunk into the question, and I have no idea how to debug this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming it's autogenerated or library code?

It is library code.

> What might I be doing that would cause a problem for code I didn't write?

You are modifying a collection in a background thread that is being iterated over in the main application thread, such as by adding or removing an overlay in a background thread.

Unfortunately, neither the classic nor the V2 version of Google Maps APIs for Android are open source, so it is difficult to tell from the stack trace what is going on precisely. My guess is that you are adding or removing overlays in a background thread.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Yes, I am adding/removing overlays in callback function. I have many points in an overlay, so when the view window changes, I delete the old overlay, and generate the new points to a new overlay. Is the proper way to go about this to manually step through the overlay and delete each point so that I can reuse the overlay?

Comment: @Akroy: " Is the proper way to go about this to manually step through the overlay and delete each point so that I can reuse the overlay?" -- if this is an `ItemizedOverlay`, the proper way is to call `populate()` on the `ItemizedOverlay` when you are ready to replace what you provided on the last `populate()` call. You will want to call `populate()` on the main application thread, AFAIK.

Comment: Forgive a newb; I'm reading about populate but I'm still unclear. Does populate essentially dump everything that was in the ItemizedOverlay before, leaving an empty Overlay to reuse?

Comment: @Akroy: "Does populate essentially dump everything that was in the ItemizedOverlay before, leaving an empty Overlay to reuse?" -- `populate()` dumps the old items and calls `size()`, `getItem()`, etc. again to reload the `OverlayItem` roster, the same as it did the first time you called `populate()`.

Comment: I think that vaguely makes sense; I can probably work out a solution from here. Thanks so much!